# Is it possible to get 13+ lookup field values in an All Items query via CSOM?

Tags: csom, lookup-column, caml-query, camlviewfields

I know I could split the queries into 2 or 3 and combine them if I only specify 4-5 lookup fields I want to retrieve each time.. But is it possible to get all of the lookup IDs with CSOM in one CAML query as you can via REST (e.g., /items?$select=AuthorId,EditorId,LookupOneId,LookupTwoId,LookupThreeId . . .LookupTwelveId)?

Answer (score 0):

Onprem you can (but shouldn't) increase this per Web Application, but in Office 365 you're limited to 12.

See [SharePoint 2010/2013: List view Lookup threshold uncovered](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2013/12/02/sharepoint-20102013-list-view-lookup-threshold-uncovered/) for more details.

Comment: Changing the threshold is not an option. I'm looking to know if I can get the lookup IDs rather than the full lookup details. If you use the GetItems REST method that allows you to submit a CAML query, the lookups are returned as ID's in the same way as the 'normal' REST api syntax. I just want to know how to specify that I am interested in those with CSOM.